# chromedriver не нажимает на кнопки на другом компьютере

Tags: python, chromedriver

Помогите разобраться: компьютер клиента, приложение python. ChromeDriverManager загружает chromedriver, он переходит по ссылкам, но как доходит дело до нажатия на кнопки на сайте -  тишина. Причем на компьютере, где писалось приложение - все работает. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: 1. Посмотрите, что выводится в консоль? Нет ли там каких-либо исключений?
2. Поставьте брекйкпоинт на предыдущем шаге и визуально посмотрите, что сейчас на экране? Присутствует ли кнопка? Активная ли она? Не перекрыта ли другими элементами?

Comment: Версия google chrome на другом компьютере совпадает?

Comment: версии, совпадают.

Answer (score 0):

проблема была в chromeDriver v103. Подробнее: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10799